# How to change search icon when user start typing in Angular

Tags: html, angular, svg, angular-material, icons

I have 2 SVG Icons in my assets folder and I have a user input box in my HTML. I want the first icon to showing as default but when ever the user start typing in the text box I want the second icon to show. I've difficult time trying to implement that.

There are the same search icon but the first icon is just plain white and the second icon is teal color.

> The default icon = search-magnifying-glass-icon.
>
> Change this when user start typing =
>   search-magnifying-glass-teal-icon.

I'm not sure if there is away to change the stroke color of SVG icon directly instead of having two icons in assets folder but this is the code for now.

HTML

```
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 380px;" >
           <input matInput [formControl]="inputCtrl" [(ngModel)]="searchText" (ngModelChange)="searchTextChanged($event)"
            placeholder="Search" class="input">
           <div class="icon"><img src="../../assets//images/icons/search-magnifying-glass-icon.svg"></div>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Some TS

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._filterTags();

    this.inputCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.death$))
      .subscribe((value: string) => {
        this._filterTags(value);
        this.updateQuery(value);
        if(value == ''){
          this.showColumn = false;

        }else{
          this.showColumn = true;
        }
      });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html u change your icon element to take parameter

```
 <div class="icon"><img [src]="icon"></div>
```

then in component create icon variable

```
icon="../../assets/images/icons/search-magnifying-glass-icon.svg"
```

then in your code

```
 this.inputCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.death$))
      .subscribe((value: string) => {
        this._filterTags(value);
        this.updateQuery(value);
        if(value == ''){
          this.showColumn = false;
          this.icon="../../assets/images/icons/search-magnifying-glass-icon.svg"
        }else{
          this.showColumn = true;
          this.icon="../../assets/images/icons/search-magnifying-glass-teal-icon"
        }
      });
```